# Auto login on specific location/network

Tags: networking, login, auto-login, automatic, location

I'm pretty new with Linux Ubuntu (18.04) and have got impression that it can be configured to do just about anything. So I wonder if there's a possibility to automatically log in at home and password login elsewhere. I thought location or specific network could be the key to make this work. Does somebody know a way to do this?